# Inserting new Activity for Case Screen by code

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to insert a new Activity for Case. The code which I have written executes without any error but it even does not inserts any Activity. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Here is the code

```html
CRActivity actiCloud9 = new CRActivity();

actiCloud9.Type = "N";      // Note
actiCloud9.Subject = current.Summary;
actiCloud9.Body = current.Description;
actiCloud9.UIStatus = current.Status;
actiCloud9.StartDate = current.StartDate;
actiCloud9.IsPrivate = true;        // current.IsInternal;
actiCloud9.RefNoteID = Base.CaseCurrent.Current.NoteID;

Base.Activities.Cache.Insert(actiCloud9);
```

Comment: Do you call a persist for the change to the database?

Comment: Also where are you calling your referenced code? in an event or an overridden method?

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I was using it in a Button click event and below code snippet provided by John has helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(Action del)
    {
        if ((Base.Case.Cache.GetStatus(Base.Case.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted || Base.Case.Cache.GetStatus(Base.Case.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Updated))
        {
            CRActivityMaint objGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CRActivityMaint>();

            CRActivity actiCloud9 = new CRActivity();

            actiCloud9.Type = "N";      // Note
            actiCloud9.Subject = "Subject";
            actiCloud9.Body = "Body";
            actiCloud9.RefNoteID = Base.CaseCurrent.Current.NoteID;

            objGraph.Activities.Cache.Insert(actiCloud9);
            objGraph.Actions.PressSave();
        }

        del();
    }
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you John. I just need to add few more fields to the update list.